# Java UserList not populating correctly upon user registration

Tags: java, swing, list, model-view-controller

I'm writing a basic user registration and login for my swing application.  Currently, the List has 3 users hardcoded in that successfully authenticate when the login button is clicked.

The issue I'm having is when I go to register a new user. I have debugged and after the new user is added to List from the registration view, the number of elements in the List increases to 4 as it should. However, when I return to the login page, the number of elements in List is back to 3, which are the users I hard coded in - this is the problem.

Here is some of my code. I'll add any if it is requested. (Also, I'm not super concerned about security at this point, I just want to get this working).

```
public class User {

private final String username;
private final String password;

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getCheckable() {
    return username.toLowerCase() + "," + password.toLowerCase();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.username + this.password;
}

public boolean equals(User user) {
    return this.username.equals(user.username) &&
           this.password.equals(user.password);
}
```

Auth method

```
public class LoginModel {

private boolean auth;
private final UserModel model;

public LoginModel() {
    model = new UserModel();
    auth = false;
}

public boolean tryAuth(User user) {
   for (int i = 0; i < model.getUserList().size(); i++) {
       if (model.getUserList().get(i).equals(user)) {
           auth = true;
       }
   }
   return auth;
}
```

UserModel

```
public class UserModel {

private final List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

public UserModel() {
    userList.add(new User("joe", "password"));
    userList.add(new User("nick", "password"));
    userList.add(new User("garrett", "password"));
}

public void addToList(User user) {
    userList.add(user);
}

public List<User> getUserList() {
    return this.userList;
}
```

LoginController - auth method is called. UserList elements = 3; (this is problem)

```
public class LoginController {

private final LoginModel model;
private final LoginView view;
private User user;

public LoginController(LoginModel model, LoginView view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;

    class LoginButtonPress implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            user = new User(view.getUserNameText(), view.getPasswordText());
            if (model.tryAuth(user)) {
                view.dispose();
                MainMenuModel menuModel = new MainMenuModel();
                MainMenuView menuView = new MainMenuView();
                MainMenuController menuController = new MainMenuController(menuModel, menuView);
            } else {
                System.out.println("incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
    view.addActionListenerLogin(new LoginButtonPress());
```

UserController - adds new user to list. UserList elements = 4;

```
public class UserController {

private final UserModel model;
private final UserView view;
private final LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();

public UserController(UserModel model, UserView view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;

    class CreateAccountButtonPress implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (view.getPasswordTextField().equals(view.getConfirmPasswordTextField())) {
                model.addToList(new User(view.getUsernameTextField(), view.getPasswordTextField())); 
                view.dispose();
                LoginView view = new LoginView();
                LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
                LoginController controller = new LoginController(model, view);
                view.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("password no match");
            }
        }
    }
    view.addActionListenerCreateAccountButton(new CreateAccountButtonPress());
```

Comment: Without valid [mcve] code posted in with your question, it will be hard to answer this, but after a quick peek at your code, I have to ask you why are you creating a completely new LoginModel within your `CreateAccountButtonPress` actionPerformed method?

Comment: It appears that you're throwing out all the changes made to the original model when you do this.

Comment: Please respond.

Comment: The problem is likely as I mentioned above, and the solution is to fix the bug in your code, not to use static. If you use static, your model becomes untestable, becomes unextendable, non-serializable, it just goes against all principles of OOP.

Comment: the reason create a new loginModel in my createAccountButtonPress is because my loginController accepts the model as a parameter

Comment: Right, but **use the original model** not a new one. When you create a new one, you discard all the information that you put into the original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of your problems:

```
class CreateAccountButtonPress implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (view.getPasswordTextField().equals(view.getConfirmPasswordTextField())) {
            model.addToList(new User(view.getUsernameTextField(), view.getPasswordTextField())); 
            view.dispose();
            LoginView view = new LoginView();
            LoginModel model = new LoginModel(); // ****** here*****
            LoginController controller = new LoginController(model, view);
            view.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("password no match");
        }
    }
}
```

You're creating a new model meaning you're discarding all the changes made to the old one. The solution is not to do this. You could pass in the old model

```
class CreateAccountButtonPress implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (view.getPasswordTextField().equals(view.getConfirmPasswordTextField())) {
            model.addToList(new User(view.getUsernameTextField(), view.getPasswordTextField())); 
            view.dispose();
            LoginView view = new LoginView();
            // LoginModel model = new LoginModel();

            // use the original updated model
            LoginController controller = new LoginController(model, view);
            view.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("password no match");
        }
    }
}
```

or better yet, simply have the controller update the view's state rather than create a new view. Your user does not want new windows thrown at him every time he adds a new user, so keep the original model **and** controller, but instead have the controller update the view whenever the model changes.

Comment: @user12345642312312143: then you have other problems as well. What do you find when you try to debug the NPE using standard NPE debugging techniques?

Comment: well im dealing with two models. the UserModel and the loginModel. Would it be wise to merge the two together into one model?

Comment: @user12345642312312143: Perhaps keep them separate classes but "merge" them via composition into an overall application model.

Answer (score 3):

Suspicious:

```
public boolean equals(User user)
```

*Never* do that. Go for

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

instead; and implement a **correct** equals comparison. You are **overloading** equals(), not **overriding**. And that achieves only one thing: causing subtle, strange bugs.

It wouldn't surprise me, if that causes objects to be overlooked when iterating your list.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I implemented that, authentication works but not against new users added

Comment: Note non-answer also given. 1+

Comment: Noticed and appreciated. And of course, if nobody else finds the real issue before I get my hands on a real keyboard I will look into this later today... Or this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating new UserModel object somewhere. You can change the UserModel class like this.

```
public class UserModel {
    private final static List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    static 
    {
        userList.add(new User("joe", "password"));
        userList.add(new User("nick", "password"));
        userList.add(new User("garrett", "password"));
    }

    public void addToList(User user) {
        userList.add(user);
    }

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return this.userList;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user12345642312312143: no! this is very wrong -- do not use static to fix a bug in your program. Instead fix the bug itself.

Comment: ughhh alright i will fix it instead, thanks for the tip